# Erro ao setar a pilha pelo kernel

Tags: assembly, stack, sistema-operacional, kernel, boot

Sempre pensei que entendia sobre a stack mas percebi que não, estou querendo entender a pilha na prática, ai criei esse ambiente

A ideia é e setar o topo da stack no endereço 7FFFh pois apartir de 8000h em diante é o kernel, depois disso  vou colocar alguma coisa na pilha entao vai estar no endereço (7FFFh - 2 = 7FFD) ja que estou em real mode, vou tentar acessar o local pelo endereço fisico

mais quando chamo o label ConfigStack ele nao funciona, fiz varios teste e se eu nao chamar esse label tudo funciona normamlmente

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x8000]

call Main
call End

Main:
    call ConfigStack
    call SetSegment
    call SetVideoMode
    call ClearScreen
ret 

ConfigStack:
    mov ax, 07E0h
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 1FEh
ret
```

Obs: ele chama todas os outros rotulos inclusive End, mais nao vou mostar o codigo porque o problema esta em ConfigStack

ClearScreen deixa a tela verde para eu ter certeza que entrei no kernel e que ele executor todas os outros labels, como eu disse tudo funciona se eu nao chamar ConfigStack

O segmento da pilha é 07E0h pois o bootloader acaba em um byte antes

| 7C00h | - **Começo do Bootloader**

|--------| - *512 bytes*

| 7DFFh | - **Fim do Bootloader**

| 7E00h | - **Começo da pilha**

| ------ | - *512 bytes*

| 7FFFh | - **Fim da pilha**

| -------|

| 8000h | **Começo do kernel**

Comment: Isso é em que plataforma? Modo real do x86 (16 bits)? Falta um pouco mais de contexto para a pergunta.

Comment: A instrução `call` coloca o endereço de retorno na pilha. Se você modificar a pilha dentro da subrotina, o `ret` irá retornar para um endereço indefinido. Normalmente, o boot seta o stack no código principal e logo no início, após normalizar todos os registradores  de segmento.